# Fill a vector in Julia with a repeated list

Tags: arrays, julia

I would like to create a column vector X by repeating a smaller column vector G of length h a number n of times. The final vector X will be of length h*n. For example

```
G = [1;2;3;4] #column vector of length h
X = [1;2;3;4;1;2;3;4;1;2;3;4] #ie X = [G;G;G;G] column vector of
length h*n
```

I can do this in a loop but is there an equivalent to the 'fill' function that can be used without the dimensions going wrong. When I try to use fill for this case, instead of getting one column vector of length h*n I get a column vector of length n where each row is another vector of length h. For example I get the following:

```
X = [[1,2,3,4];[1,2,3,4];[1,2,3,4];[1,2,3,4]]
```

This doesn't make sense to me as I know that the ; symbol is used to show elements in a row and the space is used to show elements in a column. Why is there the , symbol used here and what does it even mean? I can access the first row of the final output X by X[1] and then any element of this by X[1][1] for example.

Either I would like to use some 'fill' equivalent or some sort of 'flatten' function if it exists, to flatten all the elements of the X into one column vector with each entry being a single number.

I have also tried the reshape function on the output but I can't get this to work either.

Comment: `repeat([1,2,3,4],outer=[4])` should do it. `?repeat` at the REPL for this useful function. `repmat` is can also do it using `repmat([1,2,3,4],4,1)` but returns a matrix, not a vector.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Dan Getz for the answer:

```
repeat([1, 2, 3, 4], outer = 4)
```

Type `?repeat` at the REPL to learn about this useful function.

In older versions of Julia, `repmat` was an alternative, but it has now been [deprecated](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/26039) and absorbed into `repeat`

Answer (score 6):

As @DanGetz has pointed out in a comment, `repeat` is the function you want. From the [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/?highlight=repeat#Base.repeat):

> ```
> repeat(A, inner = Int[], outer = Int[])
> ```
>
> Construct an array by repeating the entries of `A`. The i-th element of `inner` specifies the number of times that the individual entries of the i-th dimension of `A` should be repeated. The i-th element of `outer` specifies the number of times that a slice along the i-th dimension of `A` should be repeated.

So an example that does what you want is:

```
X = repeat(G; outer=[k])
```

where `G` is the array to be repeated, and `k` is the number of times to repeat it.

---

I will also attempt to answer your confusion about the result of `fill`. Julia (like most languages) makes a distinction between vectors containing numbers and numbers themselves. We know that `fill(5, 5)` produces `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]`, which is a one-dimensional array (a vector) where each element is `5`.

Note that `fill([5], 5)`, however, produces a one-dimensional array (a vector) where each element is `[5]`, itself a vector. This prints as

```
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [5]
 [5]
 [5]
 [5]
 [5]
```

and we see from the type that this is indeed a vector of vectors. That of course is not the same thing as the concatenation of vectors. Note that `[[5]; [5]; [5]; [5]; [5]]` is syntax for concatenation, and will return `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]` as you might expect. But although `;` syntax (`vcat`) does concatenation, `fill` does not do concatenation.

Mathematically (under certain definitions), we may imagine R^(kn) to be distinct (though isomorphic to) from (R^k)^n, for instance, where R^k is the set of k-tuples of real numbers. `fill` constructs an object of the latter, whereas `repeat` constructs an object of the former.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are working with 1-dimensional arrays (Vectors)...

`X=repmat(G,4)` should do it.

--

On another note, Julia makes no distinction between row and column vector, they are both one-dimensional arrays.

`[1,2,3]==[1;2;3]` returns `true` as they are both `3-element Array{Int64,1}` or vectors (`Array{Int,1} == Vector{Int}` returns `true`)

This is one of the differences between Matlab and Julia...

If, for some specific reason you want to do it, you can create 2-dimensional Arrays (or Matrices) with one of the dimensions equal to 1.

For example:

`C = [1 2 3 4]` will create a `1x4 Array{Int64,2}` the `2` there indicates the dimensions of the Array.

`D = [1 2 3 4]'` will create a `4x1 Array{Int64,2}`.

In this case, `C == D` returns `false` of course. But neither is a Vector for Julia, they are both Matrices (`Array{Int,2} == Matrix{Int}` returns `true`).

Comment: repmat has now been deprecated: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/26039